# windows11 and windows defender performance issue

Tags: windows-defender, windows-11

I moved my laptop to windows11 about a week ago and after 3-4 days I started hearing CPU fan noise the first time, especially while I am not using the laptop CPU getting high usage. And catch the culprit "msmpeng.exe" which comes with windows defender.

I do not use any other virus protection nor many programs on this laptop. Only intellij and firefox and notepad++. What can I do to fix it ?

here how it looks
[image: msmpeng exe eats 20 percent of cpu]

I open a feedback ticket https://aka.ms/AAetifx feel free to give thumbs up if you are in windows 11.

---

when I try to change affinity of msmpeng system does not allow me
[image: set affinity]

---

when I try to run ***gpedit.msc***
[image: gpedit.msc]
result is
[image: gpedit not found]

---

### here is winver output
[image: winver from win11]

### Solution Screen Shots:

[image: gpedit in win11]
from computer configuration
[image: setting CPU amount from gpedit]

Comment: [Pure guesswork] I'd suspect Defender is running initial checks over everything on the drive, because it's a new install. It's using downtime to not upset your normal work. Once it's happy with everything it won't need to do it again & things will settle back to normal. Macs do this with every major OS update, it wouldn't surprise me if Windows now does it too.

Comment: @Tetsujin, yes, and there also was an upgrade for the Defender engine in Windows 10, and I presume 11, so it's even more likely that a full scan is being performed.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have been using this win11 for around 1 week, CPU fan started 2 days ago. overall performance is lower than win10, just sharing my observation.

Comment: If you don't provide full details, people will jump to wrong conclusions.

Comment: I update the question and gave the timetable, what else information should I put ? file explorer opens slow that makes me feel, win11 slow, and "msmpeng" was just what I caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When logged on Windows as **Administrator** press CRTL+R, then type **gpedit.msc** in the **"Open:"** field, then click on **"OK"** button.
2. On left-hand panel follow the path **"Local Computer Policy->Computer Configuration->Windows Components->Windows Defender Antivirus->Scan"**, then on right-hand panel find "Specify the maximum percentage of CPU utilization during scan" click on it 2x, then select the **Enabled** option and set the "Specify the maximum percentage of CPU utilization during scan" to **1**.

Comment: at first step I got this https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/test/issues/1#issuecomment-967962894

Comment: Are you doing those steps as **Administrator**? Try to do, please.

Comment: I ran the task manager as administrator https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/test/issues/1#issuecomment-968182904 are there any other way to run it as admin ?

Comment: Try one more time but that time **logged** as Administrator, please. I mean not just run Task Manager with Administrator permission.

Comment: The first time I enable admin and logged in with it :) look same https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/test/issues/1#issuecomment-968357404

Comment: @özkanpakdil a doubt when you start Windows and log in is **Windows Defender** not **running** any more right? I mean it's **desactivated**, right?

Comment: I did not disable ***windows defender*** I can still find msmpeng.exe in the task manager list, you can see it in the screen shots I shared.

Comment: @özkanpakdil Try the new procedure described on my answer I just changed.

Comment: thanks @Jorge-luiz, I have not run gpedit.msc around 5 years now and looks like it does not exist in win11 anymore. or at least it does not exist mine, maybe I should install it?

Comment: @özkanpakdil add on your post the Windows edition and version running on your machine. You can use the command **winver** for getting ones.

Comment: added ***winver*** to my post

Comment: @özkanpakdil ok, now try that procedure decribed in that article: [How to Install the Group Policy (Gpedit) on Windows 11](https://appuals.com/install-gpedit-msc-on-windows-10-home-edition/). Then, verify if you manage to run **gpedit.msc** normal.

Comment: I added screenshots, "Local Computer Policy->Administrive Templates->Windows Components->Windows Defender Antivirus->Scan" is not addressing the correct path, it should be "Local Computer Policy->Computer Configuration->Windows Components->Windows Defender Antivirus->Scan" just FYI.

Comment: @özkanpakdil thx! I just fixed may answer with the path informed on your previous comment.